# Can EasyLoader work with an Azure SQL database?

Tags: mapinfo

Can EasyLoader work with an Azure SQL database?

I've created a valid ODBC DSN to the Azure SQL instance, but when I try and use the EasyLoader to create the "Map Catalog", I get an error "Failed to add user MAPINFO default_database is not supported"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, EasyLoader should be able to work with a Azure SQL database.

I think the issue you are seeing is related to permission in the database/on the database server and potentially also not having specified a default database on the data source.

Try the following:
1. Make sure you have set the default database on your data source to point a the database you want to store your spatial data.

2. Create a login on the server called 'MAPINFO' with the password of 'MAPINFO'. Also assign an user on the database to this login.
3. Now try to create the MapCatalog using EasyLoader again
4. Finally, you can remove the MAPINFO login and user from the database again